# there is an error coming when I am trying to make a server using node.The nodemon is crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend, nodemon

[this is my code along with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixtSl.png)

This was supposed to make a server on the specified port. The error is Nodemon app crashed waiting for file changes before starting.I have tried changing ports it is not helping and there is no server running in the background.

Comment: Don't post an image of your code.

Comment: In `server.listen`, you are passing in the strings `"PORT"` and `"HOST"`, but not the values of the variables

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass an argument to `server.listen` as a string

```
const http = require('http');
const PORT=2000;
const HOST="localhost";

const server = http.createServer((req, res, next) => {
    if(req.url == "/about"){
        return res.end("<h1> About page</h1>")
    }
})

server.listen(PORT, HOST,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`)
})
```